# Why did Sophie Lennon offer this character a job?

Tags: the-marvelous-mrs-maisel

In *The Marvelous Mrs. Maisel* Series 2 Episode 10 'All Alone', Susie Myerson visits Sophie Lennon to try to end the rivalry between Sophie and Midge.

After an imperious speech, Sophie unexpectedly offers to take Susie on as her manager. I didn't quite follow why Sophie did this. Why did the successful and powerful Sophie Lennon offer to employ a sworn enemy, whose only relevant experience is representing Midge?

Comment: While I agree with the other answers on here, part of Sophie's motivations also stem out of jealousy. Yes, her managers don't believe in her anymore (because she is a big pain in the *ss and complete lunatic as seen in later seasons), but also she wants to take Susie away from Midge, because she's jealous and fears her fame. Their rivalry stems all the way into season 4...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, Sophie answers your question in that scene itself.

> *Sophie:* Harry Drake, he knew I wanted to be a serious actress when he signed me, but he didn't care. He didn't care about Sophie from Ann
> Arbor. He only cared about Sophie from Queens. And I thought "All
> right, become a star, Sophie. Then you can do whatever you want." And
> now I am a star. And I still slap on a fat suit night after night
> because my people don't think the audience will come see me in *A
> Street Car Named Desire*. **My people say "Stay where you are or you'll
> lose everything." They don't believe in me. I want someone to believe
> in me. To fight for me, to threaten violence for me, the way you
> threatened violence for her.**
>
> *Susie:* Miriam & I are different, we have kind of a special thing going on, a connection.
>
> *Sophie:* And I want a special thing as well. **I want someone to have passion for me. Drive, vision, fearlessness. I want you.**

Sophie is tired of her monotonous life & her managers who don't believe in her to try something different. She wants someone who cares for her, who isn't afraid to take bold chances and is fearless. Sophie sees that in Susie when she fights for Miriam against Sophie.

Answer (score 1):

Sophie Lennon dislikes the role she is playing for years... She doesn't identify with it since she has always trained to be a more formal actress. She feels her manager doesn't defend her in a way she felt Susie defend Mrs. Maisel therefore thinking Susie is the right person to have by her side.